# T-SQL CLR: Can you CREATE AGGREGATE with optional parameter(s)?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, sqlclr

I'm hoping to be able to allow optional parameters to be specified, so I can *overload* the `Accumulate()` method, **can it be done?**

I'd like to overload to allow a delimiter to specified, I've seen others where it must force a delimiter to be specified but this behaviour doesn't suit.

```sql
CREATE AGGREGATE dbo.Concatenate (@input nvarchar(max), <OPTIONAL PARAMETER HERE>)
RETURNS nvarchar(max)
```

For reference, here is the aggregate class code that contains the `Accumulate()` method I'm looking to overload:

```cs
using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;


namespace CLR.Utilities {
    /// <summary>
    /// <list type="references">
    ///     <reference>
    ///         <name>How to: Create and Run a CLR SQL Server Aggregate</name>
    ///         <link>http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/91e6taax(v=vs.90).aspx</link>
    ///     </reference>
    ///     <reference>
    ///         <name>SqlUserDefinedAggregateAttribute</name>
    ///         <link>http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.server.sqluserdefinedaggregateattribute(v=vs.90).aspx</link>
    ///     </reference>
    ///     <reference>
    ///         <name>Invoking CLR User-Defined Aggregate Functions (Provides seed code for this function)</name>
    ///         <link>http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131056.aspx</link>
    ///     </reference>
    /// </list>
    /// </summary>
    [Serializable]
    [SqlUserDefinedAggregate(
        Format.UserDefined,                 //use clr serialization to serialize the intermediate result
        IsInvariantToNulls = true,          //optimizer property
        IsInvariantToDuplicates = false,    //optimizer property
        IsInvariantToOrder = false,         //optimizer property
        MaxByteSize = -1)                   //no maximum size in bytes of persisted value
    ]
    public class Concatenate : IBinarySerialize {
        /// <summary>
        /// The variable that holds the intermediate result of the concatenation
        /// </summary>
        private StringBuilder intermediateResult;

        /// <summary>
        /// Initialize the internal data structures
        /// </summary>
        public void Init() {
            this.intermediateResult = new StringBuilder();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Accumulate the next value, not if the value is null
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="value"></param>
        public void Accumulate([SqlFacet(MaxSize = -1)] SqlString value) {
            if (value.IsNull) {
                return;
            }

            this.intermediateResult.Append(value.Value.Trim()).Append(',');
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Merge the partially computed aggregate with this aggregate.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="other"></param>
        public void Merge(Concatenate other) {
            this.intermediateResult.Append(other.intermediateResult);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Called at the end of aggregation, to return the results of the aggregation.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        [return: SqlFacet(MaxSize = -1)]
        public SqlString Terminate() {
            string output = string.Empty;
            //delete the trailing comma, if any
            if (this.intermediateResult != null
                && this.intermediateResult.Length > 0) {
                output = this.intermediateResult.ToString(0, this.intermediateResult.Length - 1).Trim();
            }

            return new SqlString(output);
        }

        public void Read(BinaryReader r) {
            intermediateResult = new StringBuilder(r.ReadString());
        }

        public void Write(BinaryWriter w) {
            w.Write(this.intermediateResult.ToString().Trim());
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the code for deployment that I'd like to modify also if optional parameters can be set:

```sql
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[Concatenate]') AND type = N'AF')
DROP AGGREGATE [dbo].[Concatenate]
GO

IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.assemblies asms WHERE asms.name = N'CLR.Utilities' and is_user_defined = 1)
DROP ASSEMBLY [CLR.Utilities]
GO

ALTER DATABASE [DatabaseName] SET TRUSTWORTHY ON
GO

CREATE ASSEMBLY [CLR.Utilities] FROM 'C:\Path\To\File\CLR.Utilities.dll' WITH PERMISSION_SET = UNSAFE
GO

CREATE AGGREGATE [dbo].[Concatenate] (@input nvarchar(max)) RETURNS nvarchar(max)
EXTERNAL NAME [CLR.Utilities].[CLR.Utilities.Concatenate]
GO

GRANT EXECUTE ON [dbo].[Concatenate] TO PUBLIC
GO
```

Comment: as far as I know, there's no way to make clr function or aggregate with optional parameters and that's sad

Comment: The "parameters" are passed to the Aggregate method, not the Init method anyway. And therein lies a potential problem - there's nothing special about the parameters that are passed - you get one copy for each row. Which implies that they could be different for each row. So, do you respect just the first? Or each of them? And then how do you decide what to do during Merge?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: good catch, I had meant to specify the Accumulate() method to be overloaded, however this more than likely wouldn't change anything anyway based on the information you've provided.

Comment: @RomanPekar Make you comment the answer and I will accept it. There is nothing available from my searching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, there's no way to make clr function or aggregate with optional parameters and that's sad.

Answer (score 1):

You could, however, make the parameter mandatory but optionally null. And, in your C# code test whether the value is null and act accordingly. Something like:

```
public void Accumulate([SqlFacet(MaxSize = -1)] SqlString value, SqlString delimiter) {
        string _delimiter;
        if (value.IsNull) {
            return;
        }

        if (delimiter.IsNull) {
            _delimiter = string.Empty;
        }
        else {
            _delimiter = Delimiter.Value;
        }

        this.intermediateResult.Append(value.Value.Trim()).Append(_delimiter);
    }
```

Comment: Once upon a time it was possible to overload Accumulate() - I did this a long while ago with VS2015/SQL2008R2.  However, today that same code was recompiled for VS2019/SQL2016 and bam! - no longer works :(  The error message during compile was utterly useless (SQL72025: DLL is corrupt).  The only way to achieve overloading is by using the method in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way, though it isn't nice.  You simple add the delimiter to the end of the column you're concatenating with a char(0) between them.  then in the clr, you can look for char(0) and grab the delimiter to use.

```
-- concat columns delimited by a comma 
select grp,dbo.clrConcat(surname) as names
  from people

-- concat column delimited by specified character
select grp,dbo.clrConcat(surname + char(0) + '|') as names
  from people
```

Then in the clr code

```
''' <summary>  
''' Initialize the internal data structures  
''' </summary>  
Public Sub Init()
    Me.intermediateResult = New StringBuilder()
    delimiter = ","
End Sub

''' <summary>  
''' Accumulate the next value, not if the value is null  
''' </summary>  
''' <param name="value"></param>  
Public Sub Accumulate(ByVal value As SqlString)
    Dim Str As String
    Dim Pos As Integer

    If value.IsNull Then Return

    Pos = value.Value.IndexOf(Chr(0))
    If Pos >= 0 Then
        Str = value.Value.Substring(0, Pos)
        If Pos + 1 < value.Value.Length Then
            delimiter = value.Value.Substring(Pos + 1, 1)
        End If
    Else
        Str = value.Value
    End If

    Me.intermediateResult.Append(Str).Append(delimiter)
End Sub
```